# CSS in react-native - syntax error <Text>

Tags: css, react-native

I'm new to js, react and css so this is going to be very basic but it's not to me. I have these containers and I'm trying to put a text field inside one of them but I'm getting syntax error at Text. Does it have something to do with < > />? Thank you

```
    <View style={styles.top}


    />
    <MapView style={styles.map}
    region ={{
    latitude:lat,
    longitude:long,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
```

}}
   >

```
    </MapView>
    <View style={styles.bottom} />


  </View>


);
```

Comment: You are closing your View two times. This : <View /> is a closing view. You should do this : <View></View>

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it does. You need to close your jsx `View` tag.

```
<View style= {styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.top}>
    <Text> Hi there</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks. I apologize but I should have posted the entire code because I am closing it further down. I have edited in the entire code, could you please take another look at why I can't add a text field in the top container?

Comment: The tags need to be arranged with the manner <View> <Text> </ Text> <MapView /> </ View>. Note the Text tag lies inside the <View> </View> and not inside the <View  <Text> </Text> />.

Answer (score 0):

The render method can only render a single root node i.e you only define one parent root in render method.
You can define multiple child root under one parent.